# Authorization header not passed on even tho it's allowed

Tags: express, http-headers

I'm unable to retrieve Authorization header from requests where I send with CORS even though I've allowed 'Authorization' in 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'. Sending with postman works.

Tried multiple different request methods including: request, axios and qwest. None of them work.

```
//Access Control in index.js before route.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Cache-Control");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT")
    next();
});
```

Expected result: Getting data back.

Actual output:

> 403 error forbidden because server can't get authorization header and error: 'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/cases/list?page=1&size=10' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.'

Comment: Have you tried adding ```res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);``` in the app.use block?

Comment: Yes, without success unfortunately.

Comment: Want to add, the authorization header is listed in the req.headers.'access-control-request-headers' but with no value.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the cors module for express solved my issue. I replaced that whole block with

```
app.use(cors({
    "origin": "*",
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "allowedHeaders": ['Authorization', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Cache-Control']
}))
```

which works. Really weird issue but I'm not gonna keep trying to figure out why it doesn't work.